# How can I set PB6 as a PWM port in STM32F103C6?

Tags: timer, stm32, pwm

I want to rotate a servo motor 180 degree.
So I decided use STM32F103C6 for controller.
I downloaded driving code from github.
There TIM2_CH1 is used and the PWM output port is PA0.
But in my board, the motor pwm pin is pluged into PB6.
Then how can I set PB6 as a PWM port.
Should I change the timer?
What do I do?
Please help me.
Thanks.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_tim.h"
#include "delay.h"
#include "lcd16x2.h"

#define DEGREE_0            0
#define DEGREE_45           45
#define DEGREE_90           90
#define DEGREE_135      135
#define DEGREE_180      180

void PWM_Init(void);
void displayServoPosition(int degree);

int main(void)
{
    DelayInit();
    lcd16x2_init(LCD16X2_DISPLAY_ON_CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF);
    
    // Initialize PWM
    PWM_Init();
    
    while (1)
    {
        // Set servo position to 0 degree
        displayServoPosition(DEGREE_0);
        TIM2->CCR1 = 520;
        DelayMs(2000);
        // Set servo position to 45 degree
        displayServoPosition(DEGREE_45);
        TIM2->CCR1 = 840;
        DelayMs(2000);
        // Set servo position to 90 degree
        displayServoPosition(DEGREE_90);
        TIM2->CCR1 = 1140;
        DelayMs(2000);
        // Set servo position to 135 degree
        displayServoPosition(DEGREE_135);
        TIM2->CCR1 = 1500;
        DelayMs(2000);
        // Set servo position to 180 degree
        displayServoPosition(DEGREE_180);
        TIM2->CCR1 = 1800;
        DelayMs(2000);
    }
}

void PWM_Init() 
{
    // Initialization struct
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStruct;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    
    // Step 1: Initialize TIM2
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);
    // Create 50Hz PWM
    // Prescale timer clock from 72MHz to 720kHz by prescaler = 100
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_Prescaler = 100;
    // TIM_Period = (timer_clock / PWM_frequency) - 1
    // TIM_Period = (720kHz / 50Hz) - 1 = 14399
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_Period = 14399;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct);
    // Start TIM2
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
    
    // Step 2: Initialize PWM
    // Common PWM settings
    TIM_OCInitStruct.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStruct.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStruct.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    // We initialize PWM value with duty cycle of 0%
    TIM_OCInitStruct.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM2, &TIM_OCInitStruct);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM2, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    
    // Step 3: Initialize GPIOA (PA0)
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    // Initialize PA0 as push-pull alternate function (PWM output) for LED
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void displayServoPosition(int degree)
{
    // Display servo position to the LCD
    lcd16x2_clrscr();
    if (degree == DEGREE_0)
    {
        lcd16x2_puts("0");
    }
    else if (degree == DEGREE_45)
    {
        lcd16x2_puts("45");
    }
    else if (degree == DEGREE_90)
    {
        lcd16x2_puts("90");
    }
    else if (degree == DEGREE_135)
    {
        lcd16x2_puts("135");
    }
    else if (degree == DEGREE_180)
    {
        lcd16x2_puts("180");
    }
    lcd16x2_putc(0xDF);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the obvious, changing `GPIOA` to `GPIOB` and `GPIO_Pin_0` to `GPIO_Pin_6`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.
Perhaps timer 2 channel 1 uses only `PA0`.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternate function table is listed in table 5 of [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c6.pdf).

Sadly for you, it looks like there is no timer function available on PB6.  You will need to connect to one of the other pins with a timer function in that table.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Then PB7, PB8, PB9, PA8, PA11?
Any one of them can be used?

Comment: You can look at the table yourself as easily as I can!  But out of those options, PA8 and PA11 have TIM1_CH1 and TIM1_CH4 respectively, PB7, PB8, PB9 have no timers.

Comment: Thanks. Then Should I replace `TIM2` to `TIM1` and `A0` to `A8`?
Only this can change the code to use TIM1_CH1?
How can I set Channel 1 in the code?
Many thanks again.

Comment: I just check a stm32f103x6 reference manual.
According to the manual, TIM4 CH1's port is PB6.
What do you think about this?
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf
page 178
Thanks.

Comment: The reference manual covers the whole family STM32F1 some of which have more timers than others. The datasheet covers your specific part, which does not have a TIM4.

Comment: Dear Tom.
I just checked the STM32F103C6 reference manual and realized you are right.
But I have to use PB6 as PWM port.
I think it can be done by interrupt function. 
But I don't know how to implement it.
I am new to STM.
Could you please share me the sample code to implement it?
Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry Edmond, I don't have time to write your project for you, that isn't how stack overflow works.